# how to use a python variable inside streamlit markdown

Tags: python, markdown, streamlit

```
  import streamlit as st
  statename = "some state name"
  d = 2000
  
  st.markdown("""
    #### "<span style="color:blue">{temp1}</span> has made {temp} calls".format(temp1 = statename, temp = str(d))    
  """,  unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Here the `.format` is now working. The whole line is treated as a string.

Output:
[image: output]

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try "f" other than .format as following?:

```
f"""
  #### "<span style="color:blue">{temp1}</span> has made {str(d)} calls"  
"""
```

see the output below:

```
  #### "<span style="color:blue">some state name</span> has made 2000 calls"
```

using .format:

```
"""
  #### "<span style="color:blue">{}</span> has made {} calls"   
""".format(statename,str(d))
```

or

```
"""
  #### "<span style="color:blue">{temp1}</span> has made {temp} calls"   
""".format(temp1=statename,temp=str(d))
```

Comment: It worked, but why?

Comment: I think .format should be outside of """ as edited. This should also work when using .format.